# calculating YTD and MTD using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have trying to implement this for about a month.
Just using some sample data from other stack-overflow questions.

```
   FinancialYearStart  MonthOfFinancialYear  SalesTotal
            2015                     1          10
            2015                     2          10
            2015                     5          10
            2015                     6          50
            2016                     1          10
            2016                     3          20
            2016                     2          30
            2017                     6          70
            2017                     7          80
```

How can we use this to calculate YTD sales total for each month.

```
FinancialYearStart  MonthOfFinancialYear  SalesTotal  YTDTotal
            2015                     1          10        10
            2015                     2          10        20
            2015                     5          10        30
            2015                     6          50        50
            2016                     1          10        60
            2016                     3          20        80
            2016                     2          30       110
            2017                     6          70        70
            2017                     7          80       150
```

to be more specific how can we calculate these metrics using a group by or by using windowing functions.

For example:

```
Year Month Customer TotalMonthlySales
2015 1 Dog 10
2015 2 Dog 10
2015 3 Cat 20
2015 4 Dog 30
2015 5 Cat 10
2015 7 Cat 20
2015 7 Dog 10
2016 1 Dog 40
2016 2 Dog 20
2016 3 Cat 70
2016 4 Dog 30
2016 5 Cat 10
2016 6 Cat 20
2016 7 Dog 10
```

Would give:

```
Year Month Customer TotalMonthlySales YTDSales
2015 1 Dog 10 10
2015 2 Dog 10 20
2015 3 Cat 20 20
2015 4 Dog 30 50
2015 5 Cat 10 30
2015 7 Cat 20 40
2015 7 Dog 10 60
2016 1 Dog 40 40
2016 2 Dog 20 60
2016 3 Cat 70 70
2016 4 Dog 30 90
2016 5 Cat 10 80
2016 6 Cat 20 100
2016 7 Dog 10 100
```

Now I am using rolling window functions to calculate last 4 weeks 13 weeks using the below approach.

```
w = (Window().partitionBy(col("number"),col("id")).orderBy(F.col("timestampGMT").cast('long')).rangeBetween(-days(27), 0))
df1 = df.withColumn('lw_4weeksCY_SALES_DOLLARS', F.sum("CY_SALES_DOLLARS").over(w)).withColumn('lw_4weeksCY_SALES_UNITS', F.sum("CY_SALES_UNITS")
```

Answer (score 1):

> you can use window function to achieve in Spark-Sql

```
df.show()
+----+-----+--------+-----------------+
|Year|Month|Customer|TotalMonthlySales|
+----+-----+--------+-----------------+
|2015|    1|     Dog|               10|
|2015|    2|     Dog|               10|
|2015|    3|     Cat|               20|
|2015|    4|     Dog|               30|
|2015|    5|     Cat|               10|
|2015|    7|     Cat|               20|
|2015|    7|     Dog|               10|
|2016|    1|     Dog|               40|
|2016|    2|     Dog|               20|
|2016|    3|     Cat|               70|
|2016|    4|     Dog|               30|
|2016|    5|     Cat|               10|
|2016|    6|     Cat|               20|
|2016|    7|     Dog|               10|
+----+-----+--------+-----------------+

df.registerTempTable("test")
sql("select *, sum(TotalMonthlySales) over(partition by year,Customer order by month) tt from test ").orderBy("year","month").show()
+----+-----+--------+-----------------+---+
|Year|Month|Customer|TotalMonthlySales| tt|
+----+-----+--------+-----------------+---+
|2015|    1|     Dog|               10| 10|
|2015|    2|     Dog|               10| 20|
|2015|    3|     Cat|               20| 20|
|2015|    4|     Dog|               30| 50|
|2015|    5|     Cat|               10| 30|
|2015|    7|     Cat|               20| 50|
|2015|    7|     Dog|               10| 60|
|2016|    1|     Dog|               40| 40|
|2016|    2|     Dog|               20| 60|
|2016|    3|     Cat|               70| 70|
|2016|    4|     Dog|               30| 90|
|2016|    5|     Cat|               10| 80|
|2016|    6|     Cat|               20|100|
|2016|    7|     Dog|               10|100|
+----+-----+--------+-----------------+---+
```

Hope this helps you. please let me know if you have any query for same